# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes when during or after opening firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox

Ubuntu 14.04 freezes during or after opening Mozilla Firefox. I have installed Ubuntu on two computers, one is a dual boot with Windows 7 and the other I just did a strait install. The same problem happens on both. I am only able to get Ubuntu to run in recovery mode on the dual boot computer. The other one doesn't give me the option for recovery mode.

Comment: Rule #1: Only ask one question per post. Please remove the stuff about viruses and ask a second question, if you feel the need. Whether you you need AV-Software or not on Ubuntu is another question which depends on your skills, activities and paranoia level... But it's normal that the GRUB boot menu doesn't show up on single boot systems. You probably need to hold down the SHIFT key before Ubuntu starts to boot to open it.

Comment: I updated Ubuntu under Ubuntu details and it seems to have fixed my problem.

Comment: Ubuntu still freezes. It happens a few seconds after I click on Firefox, System Settings or Search your Computer. I am able to use Ubuntu in recovery mode.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Could that be a bad RAM problem? Reboot your computer, and when you're in the GRUB boot menu, chose `memtest` (the shorter of the two lines) and let it run until it completed at least 100% of one entire pass. If it detects any errors, your RAM chips are faulty and need to be replaced! It might be another cause, but it's a good idea to make sure it isn't bad hardware.